# Seemingly invalid No such file or directory error

Tags: unix, ls, cd, nosuchfileexception

I'm attempting to open a directory in Unix. If I enter the command

```
ls
```

I see the directory listed in my current directory but if I endter

```
cd [directory_name]
```

I get the error

```
No such file or directory
```

I'm also not able to auto complete the directory name using the 'tab' key. Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l`? Are you sure it's a directory and not a file (or some other aspect like a process, device, etc.)?

Comment: When I input ls -l the directory I'm trying to access is listed

Comment: What about the access rights?

Comment: @BenPearce Can you provide the actual directory name that ls outputs? Likeliest explanation is probably you misinterpreting a character in the name (cyrillic с  vs c)

Comment: try cd \*directoryname\*

Answer (score 0):

This is example:

```
user@stackoverflow:~$ ls
users questions file.txt
user@stackoverflow:~$ cd /questions
user@stackoverflow:~/questions$
```

Make sure that you're trying to access a valid folder and not a file.

To further explain:

List the current directory's contents (either one):

```
ls .
ls
```

List the home directory's contents (wherever you are):

```
ls ~
```

List the root directory's contents (wherever you are):

```
ls /
```

Comment: `/` in the front means you move to the root of your file system. `~` means home and `..` parent directory. Since the root of a webserver is indeed the home, there is no difference between `questions` and `/questions` (for `@user`), but for a real file system, there is...

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought he want to access the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are using the right capitalization? It's case sensitive. Add this to your ~/.inputrc if you want bash to not care about the case of the file.

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```